# What is a proper way to say "renew a street/road"?

Tags: word-choice

I am translating a document from my language into English and I want to validate my knowledge about a statement which is **to renew a street/road**? Does it sound normal to say *to renew a street*? I want a formal version of that. Here is my translation:

> I worked as an engineering contractor in the project of renewing Safeen Quarter roads.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe, using other words, what is involved when a street is "renewed" in your language. Is it swept? Resurfaced? Realigned? Are the buildings around it improved? "Renew" does not refer to any specific activity in English, but can refer to many different kinds of revival or restoration or renovation.

Comment: [I'm translating a document, present continuous]. We say: to **repave the street**. renew is not right here. You renew a subscription to something.

Comment: In the UK we might talk of repaving a street that consisted of paving stones, I suppose, but in general you see signs saying 'This street will be closed for resurfacing from (date) to (date)', 'CAUTION - RESURFACING WORK' etc.

Comment: In America, you'd say "***repaving the road***," or you'd say "***redoing the wrote***," which is informal (e.g., Sorry I'm late. They're redoing I-94 and detouring traffic all the way down to US-12. Traffic was a bear."

Comment: In America, you'd say "***repaving the road***," or you'd say "***redoing the wrote***," which is informal (e.g., Sorry I'm late. They're redoing I-94 and detouring traffic all the way down to US-12. Traffic was a bear." Another verb you might use "resurfacing." If the road isn't concrete but asphalt, you might also say "re-blacktopping," "retarring," or "re-asphalting."

Comment: The _wrote_? Really?